Excel Offset (sample every nth row with specific values)
I'm deeply confused about using OFFSET with ROW to grab every nth row of a sheet
I have a marking sheet that looks like this:

And am trying to transfer those grades into a summary sheet where each row represents the scores for one student that are spread around the nicely formatted grading sheet

My summary sheet looks like this. In each cell I have entered the row number for each piece of information in the marking rubric.
how would I write the formula to reference these cells for the first column (Identification)? I have tried to use
OFFSET($B$5,ROW(A1)*n-1,0)
for this, but cannot figure out how to specify it to grab the right rows. e.g. 8, 44, 80, 116, etc.

I answered this myself. Thanks
I have used:
=OFFSET('Individual Sheets'!$G$1, (ROW(D1)-1)*36+8-1, 0)

Alan, you can post a formal answer and accept it if you've resolved it

@AlanNielsen For a non-volatile function, use INDEX instead of OFFSET.  eg: =INDEX($B:$B,SEQUENCE(5,,8,36)) modified as you need. If you need to return the entire row, assuming the table is in columns B:D, then =INDEX($B:$D,SEQUENCE(5,,8,36), SEQUENCE(,3)). This is entered in a single cell and the results will SPILL. Also, you must have a version of Excel that includes the SEQUENCE function. If you don't, there is another way to generate that sequence.
